# Add function to the view model in order to set the OptionText in a select element

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the following **view model**:

```
var ViewModel = function (list) {
    var self = this;
    self.selected = ko.observable("");
    self.items = ko.observableArray(list);
}
```

and this **html**:

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 
function(item) { return item.ID + ' - ' + item.Name }, value: selected">
```

Note that the code below it is working perfectly.

I would like to do some refectoring and optimize this by moving the optionsText function to the inside the view model.

So I tried (unsuccessfully) something like that:

- **view model**:

  ```
  var ViewModel = function (list) {
      var self = this;            
      self.selected = ko.observable("");            
      self.items = ko.observableArray(list);  

      self.displayName = function (item) {
          return item.ID + ' - ' + item.Name;
      }

  }
  ```
- **html**:

  ```
  <select data-bind="options: items, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 
  displayName (item???), value: selected">
  ```

The problem is that I cannot catch the current item that are being rendered, so I cannot send it to my function...

I also know that if each item it was a view model by itself I could move my displayName function to the item view model (making it as a computed function).

Anyone know how to do it? Or if it is possible to do it?

Comment: Should work with just `optionsText: displayName`, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a **reference to the function** so that Knockout will be able to pass the current item:

```
optionsText: displayName
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: items,
                   optionsValue: 'ID',
                   optionsText: displayName,
                   value: selected">
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cc4V4/25/)

Comment: I was so close... I've tried that but with a ko.computed then I realise that I was being fool by using a computed function... When I changed to a single function I never tried it without passing the parameter... Anyway, thanks a lot @haim770!